# How to "filter" a multicast with Unreal Engine?

Tags: c++, networking, server, multiplayer, unreal-engine4

I'm currently working on a multiplayer game, in which two teams (one red and one blue) fight against each other. The thing is that the server will sometimes have to some data to a specific team and not the other. I was wondering if it was possible to "filter" the multicast to prevent the server to send data to everyone ? Or to send the data to a specific list of clients ? I've been searching for a moment on several forums, and I haven't found anything interesting for the moment ^^

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Why do you want to do this out of interest, Surely you don't want clients to end up with unsynced data from the server?

Comment: I wanted to hide some actors from each other (some players from blue team aren't supposed to see some actors from red team for exemple). I finally achieved what I wanted to do by overriding the method 'IsNetRelevantFor' , with more infos here : https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/AActor/IsNetRelevantFor/index.html

Answer (score 1):

The way that a UDP broadcast works is that a network IP and a mask is provided;  machines where the ip's and mask match will get the message.

Since there's only one mask; it's designed to say what level of the network that the message should be broadcast to; but not to specific machines.

The usual way to get around this is to give each message a "topic" and then filter by topic; but still broadcast all the data to all machines.

For your specific example - you might have 3 topics.  "RedData" "BlueData" "CommonData".

Comment: I was thinking about doing it this way... It just bothers me that I'll have to send the data to anyone no matter what :/ But thanks anyway, at least it should work !

Comment: The alternative would be to not broadcast - but the cost of this is that you end up having to send the same message multiple times - but to different clients each time.

Comment: I see, not really optimized... I'll try to use the "topic" method, thanks a lot !

Comment: A multicast in Unreal is not a UDP broadcast or UDP multicast afaik.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Client RPC instead of a Multicast one, call it on the corresponding PlayerController and it will only be sent to any specific client(s).